# How to redirect only domain to another domain not subdomain & folders in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i want to redirect only my homepage to another domain -no subdomain or files should redirect
for eg:  https://example.com should redirect to https://nmg.com

but  https://subdomain.example.com  should not redirect  Also https://example.com/subfolders should not redirect  i tried searching but endup with redirecting domain + subdomain both. Any help will be apprecialted

Am noob & having this config :

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
    root /www/wwwroot/example;

    #SSL-START SSL related configuration, do NOT delete or modify the next line of commented-out 404 rules
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_START
    if ($server_port !~ 443){
        rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_END
    ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;

    #SSL-END

    #ERROR-PAGE-START  Error page configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #error_page 502 /502.html;
    #ERROR-PAGE-END

    #PHP-INFO-START  PHP reference configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    include enable-php-80.conf;
    #PHP-INFO-END

    #REWRITE-START URL rewrite rule reference, any modification will invalidate the rewrite rules set by the panel
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/example.com.conf;
    #REWRITE-END

    # Forbidden files or directories
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
    {
        return 404;
    }
    
      index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 

    # Directory verification related settings for one-click application for SSL certificate
    location ~ \.well-known{
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log off; 
    }
    access_log  /www/wwwlogs/example.com.log;
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/example.com.error.log;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if ($server_port !~ 443){
    rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

You can try (in the following order):

```
set $joined $host$uri;
if ($joined = example.com/) {
    return 301 https://nmg.com/;
}
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```